# How to tokenise on hyphens using unnest_tokens in R

Tags: regex, tidytext

I'm trying to tokenise a dataframe containing strings. Some contain hyphens, and I'd like to tokenise on hyphens using unnest_tokens()

I've tried upgrading tidytext from 0.1.9 to 0.2.0
I've tried a number of variations on regex to capture the hyphen from:

```
df <- data.frame(words = c("Solutions for the public sector | IT for business", "Transform the IT experience - IT Transformation - ITSM")

df %>% 
unnest_tokens(query, words, 
                token = "regex",
                pattern = "(?:\\||\\:|[-]|,)")
```

I expect to see:

```
query
solutions for the public sector
it for business
transform the it experience
it transformation
itsm
```

instead, I get the tokenised no hyphen lines:

```
query
solutions for the public sector
it for business
```

Comment: Try `df %>% unnest_tokens(query, words, token = stringr::str_split, pattern = "[-:,|]")`

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
library(stringr)
df %>%  
  unnest_tokens(query, words, token = stringr::str_split, pattern = "[-:,|]")
```

This command will use `stringr::str_split` to split against the `[-:,|]` pattern: `-`, `:`, `,` or `|` chars. Note they do not need to be escaped inside a character class/bracket expression. The hyphen does not need to be escaped when it is the first or last char, and the others are just not special in a character class.